# Bad characters in a console log output QtCreator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

How to fix this bad characters? I use `Qt 5.7.1 MSVC 2015 32 bit`, to note that `Qt 5.7.1 MinGW` works fine.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it was an old [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-316).
To solve it I changed my `Regional and Language Setttings` in `Control Panel` from `Russian` to `English`.

**UPDATE**
Just set your MVC to english.